# set empty values in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to set some values for the devices that don't have that parameters but for dataPersist and each of the timestamps is not working. I don't know if it'a a problem of the if structure I'm using, but for dataContainer and dataImageList is working.

```
 public getDeviceById = (deviceId: string): Promise<IDevice> => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            Device.findOne({ _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(deviceId) }).then((doc: any) => {
                if (doc) {

                    if  (!doc.dataPersist) {
                        Device.updateOne({_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(deviceId) }, { $set: { dataPersist: { persistSize: "", timestamp: new Date()} }})
                    }
                    if (!doc.dataContainer) {

                        Device.updateOne({_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(deviceId) }, { $set: { dataContainer: { containerInfo:[], dockerInfo: [], timestamp: new Date()} }})
                    }

                    if(!doc.dataImageList) {

                        Device.updateOne({_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(deviceId) }, { $set: { dataImageList: { imageList:[], timestamp: new Date()} }})
                    }

                        resolve(doc);


                } else {
                    reject("fieldNotFoundError,device,getDeviceById");
                }
            }).catch((err: any) => {
                console.error(err);
                reject("databaseError,043");
            });
        });
    }
```

Why is that?

This is my model:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { IDevice } from "./iDevice";

interface IDeviceModel extends IDevice, mongoose.Document {
}

const deviceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    dataPersist: {
        persistSize: String,
        timestamp: Date
    },
    dataImageList: {
        imageList: Array,
        timestamp: Date
    },
    dataContainer: {
        containerInfo: Array,
        dockerInfo: Array,
        timestamp: Date
    }
});

const Device = mongoose.model<IDeviceModel>("device", deviceSchema);

export = Device;
```

Thank in advance for your help.

Comment: did you try setting `' '` with just space?

Comment: The problem resides in `Device.updateOne` which is **asynchronous**. You should set these empty objects to `doc` object and perform update only once.

Comment: Hi Saikat. No, I didn't, but timestamp is not working. Is that the way to set an empty Date?

Comment: Ok, Valijon, I'll try that.

Comment: @user149575 there is nothing called empty date though, what you set there (`new Date()`) is the current timestamp.